# Partition of the Set of Subests of A induced by R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

$A$ is a non-empty set and $B$ is a fixed subset of A. The relation R on
the set of subsets of A as follows.
Relation is defined by:
$R = \{(X,Y) | X \cap B = Y \cap B\}$
where $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of $A$.

I can show that this relation is an equivalence relation. However, the question also asks me the following:
If $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$ find the partition of the set of subsets of $A$
induced by $R$.

I could not really understand the expression. Textbook says that equivalence classes of $R$ form a partition of $S$. Should I check every subset of $A$ and find their equivalence classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your idea is the good one. Take any subset of $ X \subseteq A$ (there is only 8 of those) and compute $X \cap B$ (easy!). Then look at the values of $X \cap B$ to find the equivalence classes.

You’ll find

$\overline{\{1\}}=\{\{1\}, \{1,3\}\}$, $\overline{\{2\}}=\{\{2\}, \{2,3\}\}$, $\overline{\emptyset}=\{\emptyset, \{3\}\}$, $\overline{\{1,2\}}=\{\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$

Comment: By doing that, I obtained an answer in the following form
[({1,2,3},{1,2}),({1,2},{1,2}),({1},{1}),({1},{1,3}),({2},{2,3}),({2},{2}),({1,3},{1,3}),({1,3},{1}),({2,3},{2,3}),({2,3},{2}),({3},{3})]
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you found the elements of $R$. To find the equivalence classes, you now need to find the groups  of elements that are all in relation. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing; as far as I know, partition should not include empty set, but in the answer you gave above there is also empty set. Why?

Comment: Good question ! Note the bar over the $\emptyset$... meaning that this is not the emptyset but the class of the emptyset, which as you can see contains two sets (that are subsets of $\{1 ,2,3\}$.